# Python 'TypeError': 'Generator' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to perform a simple Euclid example in Python but receive the error mentioned in the title. The code is as follows:

```
def gcd1(a,b):
        """ the euclidean algorithm """
        while a:
                a, b = b%a, a
        return b
```

I'm calling the code as follows (i think this might have something to do with it):

```
for x in set1:
    print(gcd1(x, set2[x]))
```

**Edit: current situation (works)**

```
set1 = list(range(start, end))
""" otherrange() behaves just like range() however returns a fixed list"""
set2 = list(otherrange(start, end))

for x in set1:
    print(gcd1(x, set2[x]))
```

Comment: Can you tell us which line had the error and what set2 is?

Comment: What is `otherrange()` here?

Comment: just range with other parameters

Comment: @Ropstah: `range()` in Python is not a generator, yet your problem indicates you *do* have such an object. Please give us something that'll let us *reproduce the problem*. Only then can we give you a solution that'll work optimally, rather than just apply the `list()` plaster.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `otherrange` is a custom method which basically returns an list of numbers. Whereas the rest of my implementation could greatly benefit from optimization my question here is answered. I'd love to go on and chat about the problem.

Comment: @Ropstah: Then *show us the definition of `otherrange`, because it appears to return a generator, where you may not need to return one at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that `set2` is a generator, to get around this just turn it into a list.

```
set2_list = list(set2)
for x in set1:
    print(gcd1(x, set2_list[x]))
```

Comment: @Ropstah Hold on, what I put earlier may not work as expected.  Use my updated answer.

Comment: I already used variables but those pointed to the functions. I simply wrapped all in a list, so it was all good (right?)

Comment: @Ropstah yeah, I guess so